# Are there differential forms on $\Bbb{R}^n$ which are neither exact nor closed

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

There are exact differential forms on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (all of which are closed).  There are closed forms which are not exact.  I'd like an example of a differential form on $\Bbb{R}^n$ which is neither exact nor closed.

Comment: Just make up any differential form at random, and chances are good that you have your example...

Comment: What have you tried? Virtually any form is not going to be closed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's not quite true.  There are $0$-forms on $\mathbb R^n$ which are closed but not exact.

Comment: @Aweygan What about it? A "constant" one-form is certainly exact --  if $a$ and $b$ are constant then $adx+bdy = d(ax+by)$. Ok, I should admit that all I had in mind was one-forms; I suppose a constant _function_ could be regarded as a closed 0-form, which can't be exact just because there's no such thing as a (-1)-form.

Answer (score 0):

Most forms on $\mathbb R^n$ are not closed.  For zero forms, any nonconstant function is not closed.  For $1\leq k<n$, let $I$ be a subset of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $|I|=k$.  define 
$$\omega=\left(\prod_{i\in[n]\setminus I}x^i\right)dx^I$$
Then 
$$d\omega=\sum_{j\in[n]\setminus I}\left(\prod_{i\in[n]\setminus(I\cup\{j\})}x^i\right)dx^jdx^I\neq 0$$
Indeed, for any smooth function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ with some nonzero partial derivative, you can define a differential form which is not closed.